criterion on if an 1-dim random walk is transient
Consider a random walk on $\mathbb{Z}_+={0,1,2,...}$ with a reflection barrier on $0$. That is, $p_{i,i+1}:=p_i, p_{i,i-1}:=q_i=1-p_i$, $p_0=1,p_i>0,q_i>0$. I got the following criterion somewhere I forgot:
$$\text{the RW be transient} \iff \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{q_1\cdots q_n}{p_1\cdots p_n}<\infty$$

Is is correct?
If it is, how to prove it; If not, is there any useful criterion else?

I tried my hands on calculating $\sum p_{00}^{(n)}<\infty$ or $f_{00}=\sum f_{00}^{(n)}<1$ but failed to figure it out. Can you help me?
Any comments or solutions will be fully appreciated!
